# js functions in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am just looking into improving my JS skills i get JS and some of how it works but am a little confused on how Jquery plugins work.

I have started this Plugin.
when this is just standalone functions being called it work's fine but i want it to be a plugin.

```
(function ( $ ) {

  $.fn.countdown = function( options ) {

    // This is the easiest way to have default options.
    var settings = $.extend({
        // These are the defaults.
        daySelector : "",
        hourSelector : "",
        minuteSelector : "",
        secondSelector : "",
        launchDate : new Date("December 25, 2013 12:01:00"),
        procentageDone : 1,
        headerColor : 'yellow',
        progressFillColor : 'green',    
        description : {header:"Header",text:"sample text."} 

    }, options );


    var secondsRemaining = Math.floor(settings.launchDate.getTime() / 1000) - Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

    /* Functions calls for countdown*/
    count(secondsRemaining);
    updateProgress(settings.procentageDone);
    setHeaderColor(settings.headerColor);
    setProgressFillColor(settings.progressFillColor);
    setProgressDescription(settings.description['header'], settings.description['text']);

     /* countdown functions */
    var count = function(secondsRemaining) {
        alert(secondsRemaining)
        var days = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 86400),
            hours = Math.floor((secondsRemaining - (days * 86400)) / 3600),
            minutes = Math.floor((secondsRemaining - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)) / 60),
            seconds = secondsRemaining - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if(secondsRemaining > 0) {
            if(days < 10) { days = '0' + days; }
            if(hours < 10) { hours = '0' + hours; }
            if(minutes < 10) { minutes = '0' + minutes; }
            if(seconds < 10) { seconds = '0' + seconds; }

            $('.days > .number').html(days);
            $('.hours > .number').html(hours);
            $('.minutes > .number').html(minutes);
            $('.seconds > .number').html(seconds);

            secondsRemaining--;

        } else {

            if(secondsRemaining == 0) {window.location.reload();}
        }
        window.setTimeout(function() {countdown(secondsRemaining); }, 1000);

    }
    var updateProgress = function (procent) {

        if(typeof procent !== "number") {procent = 0;}

        if(procent <= 7) {

            $('.progressBarFill').css({ width: '7%' }).find('.progressBarFillMiddle').html(procent + '%');
        } else if(procent >= 100) {
            $('.progressBarFill').css({ width: '100%' }).find('.progressBarFillMiddle').html('100%');

        } else {
            $('.progressBarFill').css({ width: procent + '%' }).find('.progressBarFillMiddle').html(procent + '%');
        }

    }
    var setProgressDescription = function (header, text){

        $('.progressDescriptionMiddle').find('.DescriptionHeader').html(header);
        $('.progressDescriptionMiddle').find('.DescriptionText').html(text);
    }
    var objectConverter = function (array) {
        var object = {};
        for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            object[array[i]] = '';
        }
        return object;
    }
    var setHeaderColor = function (color) {
        color = color.toLowerCase();
        if(typeof color === "undefined") {
            color = 'yellow';
        }
        if(color in objectConverter(['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'red', 'gray'])) {
            $('.header').attr('class', 'header').addClass(color);
        }
    }
    var setProgressFillColor = function (color) {

        color = color.toLowerCase();
        if(typeof color === "undefined") {
            color = 'green';
        }
        if(color in objectConverter(['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'red', 'gray'])) {
            $('.progressBarFill').attr('class', 'progressBarFill clear').addClass(color);
        }
    }


    };

}( jQuery ));
```

and i want to call it like

```
        $.countdown({
            launchDate : new Date("December 25, 2013 12:01:00"),
            procentageDone : 1,
            headerColor : 'yellow',
            progressFillColor : 'green',    
            description:{header:"Header Text", text:"this is sample text."} 

        });
```

but as im unsure on how you would call a function in the plugin to make this work.
please help me out and clear up my thoughts on this matter.

Comment: Try reading this: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Comment: A jQuery plugin is normally attached to $.fn and called on a collection of elements, otherwise it's just a function attached to the jQuery namespace, and is called as $.countdown.

Comment: Keep in mind that `jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype`. It makes it easier to "click" when you learn JavaScript knowing jQuery or the other way around.

Comment: oh ok so does it need to be $.fn.countdown = function (blah){};

and call by $.countdown, but how do i get the functions inside the plugin to work.

Comment: @MasterT yes. Then you have syntax errors in function declarations like `count: function()`, it should be `var count = function()`.

Comment: ok made edit .. does this look like its correct.